# Matrix Computations Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have a function where I am calculating a value as:

```
a = a + pow(b - np.dot(A[i,:],B[:,j]), 2)    
final_Result= a + C * ((np.square(A)).sum() +(np.square(B)).sum() )
print final_Result
func.extend(final_Result)   
# C is a float value
```

It shows me result as

```
      [[ 455.83301538]]
      >>> func
       [matrix([[ 455.83301538]])]
```

I can get final.item(0) from the console (IPython). But I couldn't do it in the program. What I am doing wrong here? How can I get the value alone from the final matrix??

Comment: "But I couldn't do it in the program" - Was there an error? If yes, which? If no, what happened?

Comment: What's the actual result in console and in program? I can bet it's IPython's magic's work.

Comment: It is not showing any error. But I couldn't get the value alone from the matrix

Comment: The results are same but the format is different

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `finalResult` is a 1x1 [matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#matrix-objects).  If you print `finalResult`, you get the "str" or "nice" representation of `finalResult`.  This format of the matrix doesn't include the text `matrix(` and the closing `)`; it just shows the numbers in square brackets.  If you enter `finalResult` in a python prompt, it echoes back the "repr" of `finalResult`; this include the text `matrix(...)`.  You can also get this format using the builtin function `repr()`.

For example (using `a` instead of `finalResult`),

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.matrix([[1.25]])
>>> print(a)
[[1.25]]
>>> a
matrix([[1.25]])
>>> print(repr(a))
matrix([[1.25]])
```

You put `finalResult` in the list `func`, which is basically the same as this:

```
>>> [a]
[matrix([[1.25]])]
```

To get the value out of the matrix, you can use regular array indexing:

```
>>> a[0,0]
1.25
```